# How to Alter all specific datatype to another datatype in whole table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table `table_name` with 50 decimal(18, 0) columns and I want to change it's datatype to decimal(18, 6)

I am trying

```
ALTER TABLE [table_name] ALTER COLUMN [column_name] [data_type]
```

But for this, I have to queries 50 times.

How I do it in a single Query

Comment: Create dynamic sql query and execute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it easily by executing a dynamic sql query.

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);

select @sql = stuff((
        select 'alter table [your_table_name] 
        alter column [' + [column_name] + '] decimal(18, 6);'
        from information_schema.columns
        where [table_name] = 'your_table_name'
        and [data_type] = 'decimal'
        for xml path('')
    )
    , 1, 0, ''
);

exec(@sql);
```

Comment: `where [table_name] = 't20171207'` should be where [table_name] = 'your_table_name'

Comment: I dont know why `&#x0D` characters added in @sql

Comment: I resolved it with this `SET @sql = (REPLACE(REPLACE(@sql,'&#x0D',''),'[_TESTDETDET] ;','[_TESTDETDET] '));
exec(@sql);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add all colunm seprated by comma i.e.

ALTER TABLE [table_name] ALTER COLUMN [column_name1] [data_type],[column_name2] [data_type],so on;

Comment: read my question, i allready mension that it should be in single query, what we do when columns are dynamic